# AngularJS TypeAhead - take a different attribute for ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js

http://jsfiddle.net/H7LA4/275/

I want to display the id of the selected state instead of the state name above the input box. How can I refactor the code to show the id of the selected state?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl"> <pre>State: {{selected}}</pre>

        <input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = [{name: 'Alabama',id: 1}, {name: 'New York',id: 2}, {name: 'Calafornia',id: 3}];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

*typeahead-on-select*

callback to have more control and do extra computations if needed

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl"> 
      <pre>State: {{selectedId}}</pre>

        <input 
        class="input-large" 
        type="text" 
        ng-model="selected" 
        typeahead="state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
        typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = [{name: 'Alabama',id: 1}, {name: 'New York',id: 2}, {name: 'Calafornia',id: 3}];

    $scope.onSelect = function ($item, $model, $label, $even) {
        $scope.selectedId = $item.id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

to

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.id as state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

Comment: This makes the select box have the value of the id on select. Instead of the name

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer, and if someone wants to achieve this without additional callbacks, you can use

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state as state.name for state in states | filter: $viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

This will bind the whole object to the `selected` model, so you can make use of `selected.id` and `selected.name`.
And then if you want to disable filter by id, just change `filter: $viewValue` to `filter: {name: $viewValue}`